# I want to create a message box to enter in the cell data that I want to filter by

Tags: excel, vba

I am looking to filter by certain names, for example, JHILL2. I would like a message box to pop up where I can enter in JHILL2 and then filter in a certain column by that.

I currently have code which is just for JHILL2 but would like to have the option box to change the name each time I run the macro

```
Sub filter_jhill2()

    Set ws = Worksheets("modified_report")

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Sheets("modified_report").Select

    'Selection.AutoFilter
    Worksheets("modified_report").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="JHILL2"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a variable through an inputbox

```
Dim criteria As String
criteria = InputBox("What name would you like to filter the column with?")
```

Then change the filter, which i presume works:

```
Worksheets("modified_report").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:= criteria
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working with the following code:

```
Sub filter_by_acr()

   Set ws = Worksheets("modified_report")

   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

   strInput = InputBox("Enter acronym to filter on")

   Worksheets("modified_report").Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=strInput

End Sub
```